# OpenCV image Comparison And Similarity in Android

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm `OpenCV` learner. I was trying Image Comparison. I have used **OpenCV 2.4.13.3**
I have these two images `1.jpg` and `cam1.jpg`.

[image]  [image]

When I use the following command in openCV

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path1, path2;
path1 = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/1.jpg";
path2 = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/cam1.jpg";

FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.BRIEF);
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

Mat img1 = Highgui.imread(path1);
Mat img2 = Highgui.imread(path2);

Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
extractor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

//second image
// Mat img2 = Imgcodecs.imread(path2);
Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
extractor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);


//matcher image descriptors
MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2,matches);

// Filter matches by distance
MatOfDMatch filtered = filterMatchesByDistance(matches);

int total = (int) matches.size().height;
int Match= (int) filtered.size().height;
Log.d("LOG", "total:" + total + " Match:"+Match);
```

**Method filterMatchesByDistance**

```
    static MatOfDMatch filterMatchesByDistance(MatOfDMatch matches){
    List<DMatch> matches_original = matches.toList();
    List<DMatch> matches_filtered = new ArrayList<DMatch>();

    int DIST_LIMIT = 30;
    // Check all the matches distance and if it passes add to list of filtered matches
    Log.d("DISTFILTER", "ORG SIZE:" + matches_original.size() + "");
    for (int i = 0; i < matches_original.size(); i++) {
        DMatch d = matches_original.get(i);
        if (Math.abs(d.distance) <= DIST_LIMIT) {
            matches_filtered.add(d);
        }
    }
    Log.d("DISTFILTER", "FIL SIZE:" + matches_filtered.size() + "");

    MatOfDMatch mat = new MatOfDMatch();
    mat.fromList(matches_filtered);
    return mat;
}
```

**Log**

```
total:122 Match:30
```

As we can see from the log match is 30.
But as we can see both images have same visual element (in).
How can I get match=90 using openCV?
It would be great if somebody can help with code snippet.
If using opencv it is not possible then what are the other 
alternatives we can look for?

Comment: This feels like a question looking for a tutorial on OpenCV and/or image recognition. I'm linking to a different SE group, where reading posts like: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17846/template-matching-or-object-recognition may provide the appropriate context for further research.

Comment: Why don't you change the threshold `DIST_LIMIT`? What is the purpose of getting more matches, if 30 is enough?

Comment: 30 is not enough.

Comment: This looks a challenging image for ORB/SIFT descriptors.... it has basically 2 colors, and most of the descriptors (if not all) will be around the edges, which are similar to a lot of the other edges, so you will get a lot of false positives (best match being farther than you think) and when filtered by distance you get only the ones closest to it. Maybe you have to try another method, more like pattern matching or so

Comment: @api55 please help with code

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/matchmethod_orb_akaze_brisk.cpp Have you checked this? Gives good results with your images.

Comment: I do agree with @api55, feature detection/matching is not suited for these kind of images since they won't yield enough unique keypoints. You should have more luck with [pattern matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) which unfortunately is not robust to rotations. Also, please refrain from specifically  asking for code, SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 7):

> But as we can see both images have same visual element (in).

So, we should compare not whole images, but "same visual element" on it. You can improve `Match` value more if you do not compare the "template" and "camera" images themselves, but processed same way (converted to binary black/white, for example) "template" and "camera" images. For example, try to find blue (background of template logo) square on both ("template" and "camera") images and compare that squares (Region Of Interest). The code may be something like that:

```
Bitmap bmImageTemplate = <get your template image Bitmap>;
Bitmap bmTemplate = findLogo(bmImageTemplate);  // process template image

Bitmap bmImage = <get your camera image Bitmap>;
Bitmap bmLogo = findLogo(bmImage); // process camera image same way

compareBitmaps(bmTemplate, bmLogo);
```

where

```
private Bitmap findLogo(Bitmap sourceBitmap) {
    Bitmap roiBitmap = null;
    Mat sourceMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(sourceBitmap, sourceMat);
    Mat roiTmp = sourceMat.clone();

    final Mat hsvMat = new Mat();
    sourceMat.copyTo(hsvMat);

    // convert mat to HSV format for Core.inRange()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(hsvMat, hsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

    Scalar lowerb = new Scalar(85, 50, 40);         // lower color border for BLUE
    Scalar upperb = new Scalar(135, 255, 255);      // upper color border for BLUE
    Core.inRange(hsvMat, lowerb, upperb, roiTmp);   // select only blue pixels

    // find contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Rect> squares = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(roiTmp, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // find appropriate bounding rectangles
    for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
        MatOfPoint2f areaPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
        RotatedRect boundingRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(areaPoints);

        double rectangleArea = boundingRect.size.area();

        // test min ROI area in pixels
        if (rectangleArea > 400) {
            Point rotated_rect_points[] = new Point[4];
            boundingRect.points(rotated_rect_points);

            Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(rotated_rect_points));
            double aspectRatio = rect.width > rect.height ?
                    (double) rect.height / (double) rect.width : (double) rect.width / (double) rect.height;
            if (aspectRatio >= 0.9) {
                squares.add(rect);
            }
        }
    }

    Mat logoMat = extractSquareMat(roiTmp, getBiggestSquare(squares));

    roiBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(logoMat.cols(), logoMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(logoMat, roiBitmap);
    return roiBitmap;
}
```

method `extractSquareMat()` just extract Region of Interest (logo) from whole image

```
public static Mat extractSquareMat(Mat sourceMat, Rect rect) {
    Mat squareMat = null;
    int padding = 50;

    if (rect != null) {
        Rect truncatedRect = new Rect((int) rect.tl().x + padding, (int) rect.tl().y + padding,
                rect.width - 2 * padding, rect.height - 2 * padding);
        squareMat = new Mat(sourceMat, truncatedRect);
    }

    return squareMat ;
}
```

and `compareBitmaps()` just wrapper for your code:

```
private void compareBitmaps(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
    Mat mat1 = new Mat(bitmap1.getWidth(), bitmap1.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap1, mat1);

    Mat mat2 = new Mat(bitmap2.getWidth(), bitmap2.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap2, mat2);

    compareMats(mat1, mat2);
}
```

your code as method:

```
private void compareMats(Mat img1, Mat img2) {
    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.BRIEF);
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

    Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
    extractor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

    //second image
    // Mat img2 = Imgcodecs.imread(path2);
    Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
    extractor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);


    //matcher image descriptors
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2,matches);

    // Filter matches by distance
    MatOfDMatch filtered = filterMatchesByDistance(matches);

    int total = (int) matches.size().height;
    int Match= (int) filtered.size().height;
    Log.d("LOG", "total:" + total + " Match:" + Match);
}

static MatOfDMatch filterMatchesByDistance(MatOfDMatch matches){
    List<DMatch> matches_original = matches.toList();
    List<DMatch> matches_filtered = new ArrayList<DMatch>();

    int DIST_LIMIT = 30;
    // Check all the matches distance and if it passes add to list of filtered matches
    Log.d("DISTFILTER", "ORG SIZE:" + matches_original.size() + "");
    for (int i = 0; i < matches_original.size(); i++) {
        DMatch d = matches_original.get(i);
        if (Math.abs(d.distance) <= DIST_LIMIT) {
            matches_filtered.add(d);
        }
    }
    Log.d("DISTFILTER", "FIL SIZE:" + matches_filtered.size() + "");

    MatOfDMatch mat = new MatOfDMatch();
    mat.fromList(matches_filtered);
    return mat;
}
```

As result for resized (scaled for 50%) images  saved from your question result is:

> ```
> D/DISTFILTER: ORG SIZE:237
> D/DISTFILTER: FIL SIZE:230
> D/LOG: total:237 Match:230
> ```

NB! This is a quick and dirty example just to demonstrate approach only for given template.

P.S. `getBiggestSquare()` can be like that (based on compare by area):

```
public static Rect getBiggestSquare(List<Rect> squares) {
    Rect biggestSquare = null;

    if (squares != null && squares.size() >= 1) {
        Rect square;
        double maxArea;
        int ixMaxArea = 0;

        square = squares.get(ixMaxArea);
        maxArea = square.area();

        for (int ix = 1; ix < squares.size(); ix++) {
            square = squares.get(ix);
            if (square.area() > maxArea) {
                maxArea = square.area();
                ixMaxArea = ix;
            }
        }

        biggestSquare = squares.get(ixMaxArea);
    }

    return biggestSquare;
}
```

Comment: This is will work only for blue logo. what about for other logos. i have 10-12 logo.

Comment: Most likely it's possible to create rules for ROI extraction for all cases and test logos similarity in loop one by one. But if you have many logos (patterns) with complex shapes (e.g. pictures with gradients) better way is to use machine learning based approach. Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@daj/creating-an-image-classifier-on-android-using-tensorflow-part-1-513d9c10fa6a) or [that](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/#0) tutorials.

Comment: what is the `getBiggestSquare` method ?

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko please show function: getBiggestSquare()

Comment: @CodeKadiya Please take look at P.S.