# How to match image on different android devices?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, automated-tests

I need to detect same image(icon) on different android devices.
The whole screen is  a canvas so I'am using 'matchTemplate' method  from 'cv2' library to detect the images. 
Because there are multiple devices with different sizes(inch) and resolution.
I'am using the cv2.resize() method . I make resizing accoring to size screen size in pixels.

```
data = device.info
scr_width = data["displayWidth"]
scr_hight = data["displayHeight"]
width_new = int((width*scr_width)/width_standard)
height_new = int((height*scr_hight)/height_standart)
new_img_lock =  cv2.resize(image, (height_new,width_new))
```

width_standard - is the width of my original icon.
It seems to work on the devices with the same screen size(inches)
and same resolution but how to resize it for devices with different screen sizes and resolutions?

Comment: Look into feature detection and matching.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45932979/6950238) question and answer.